# How to show drop shadows on LIs in a 960 grid based layout?

Tags: css, dropshadow, grid-layout

I am trying to create a page showing a list of products in a grid (960.gs) format. To match the COMP, I need to show a drop shadow on a LI when the user hovers above it.

Showing the drop shadow on a hover is simple, but showing it the way as it is in COMP is turning out to be a difficult task to complete and I need some assistance.

Below is the screen-shot of the COMP I have to match.

[image]

The numbers 1 to 10 are grids. I am using ULs to create rows and LIs to show product items in the row.

```
<!-- loops n times for n rows -->
<UL class="container_10 clearfix">
    <!-- loops 5 times for 5 list items in a row -->
    <LI class="grid_2 product">
        <UL>
            <LI class="prodImg clearfix">...</LI>
            <LI class="prodTitle clearfix">...</LI>
            <LI class="prodPrice clearfix">...</LI>
            <LI class="prodPromo clearfix">...</LI>
            <LI class="prodReviews clearfix">...</LI>
        </UL>
    </LI>
</UL>
```

As can be seen in the screen-shot the shadow flows out of the grid layout.... I have now clue how to incorporate that here.

edit: As per project requirements we are only supporting modern browsers, so no worries about IE6 or other junk browsers, I am allowed to use CSS3 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need to accommodate less accommodating browsers, I would use a combination of pseudoelements and CSS box-shadow:

```
CSS:
.product {
  position: relative;
}
.product:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}
.product:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #CCC;
}
```

The `.product:after` declaration creates an element outside of the flow of the document positioned relative to the `.product` element. The `.product:hover:after` declaration creates the drop shadow. Adjust the measurements, etc. to fit your mockup.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/SMqDx/

Comment: Thanks a ton @Brent... I never thought about using :after selector. That certainly gets me going. Now I simply need to make some changes to make sure that the height of the shadow always remains the same throughout the row (UL) and does not size down for products listed (LI) with less content.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `position:relative` to your LI tags, you could add an html element inside it that would be absolutely positioned outside and placed under the product image and infos.

If you want to avoid adding another html element, you could even use `li:after` to add it. I don't know if this is clear enough, if not, just ask, I'll try to provide a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use `box-shadow` to give your product boxes shadows when hovered?

```
.product li:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black; /* Whatever size shadow you need */
}
```

Example of similar code: http://jsfiddle.net/6zcqZ/

#### EDIT

Looks like you may be wanting to use the `<spread>` property of box shadows, as defined below:

```
box-shadow: [x-offset] [y-offset] [blur value] [spread value] [color];
```

So, instead of the above, [you could simply add the spread value](http://jsfiddle.net/6zcqZ/1/), such as:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
```

Comment: I could, but the problem is that the drop shadow needs to be of different size than the containing LI... so we need to add some logic to cast a shadow bigger than what LI is being hovered on.

Comment: Ah, you'd probably want to use the box shadow's `spread` value - I updated my answer to reflect that.